# How to passe data and a value from a array in a xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

In my android application, I get values from a array defined in string.xml file and use it in a java activity class. It was working charmly before I have to work with Arabic fonts.

When I put Arrabic letters in the xml file, I can't compere them in the java file.
it shows error `"Some characters can not be mapped using cp1252"`
Here is the xmle array with Arrabic

```
<string-array name="country_arrays">

        <item>لا شيء</item>
        <item>5 &#8211; 9</item>
        <item>10 &#8211; 14</item>
        <item>15 &#8211; 19</item>
        <item>20 &#8211; 24</item>
        <item>25 &#8211; 35</item>
        <item>36 &#8211; 45</item>

    </string-array>
```

Here is the java code

```
if (s.equals("5 &#8211; 9")) {
                        message = getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc1);

                    } else if (s.equals("10 &#8211; 14")) {
                        message = getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc1);
                    } else if (s.equals("15 &#8211; 19")) {
                        message = getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc2);
                    } else if (s.equals("20 &#8211; 24")) {
                        message = getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc3);
                    } else if (s.equals("25 &#8211; 29")) {
                        message = getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc4);
                    } else if (s.equals("30 &#8211; 34")) {
                        message = getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc5);
                    } else if (s.equals("35 &#8211; 39")) {
                        message = getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc6);
                    } else if (s.equals("40 &#8211; 44")) {
                        message = getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc7);
                    } else if (s.equals("45 &#8211; 49")) {
                        message = getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc8);
                    } else if(s.equals(ذلك)){
                        message = getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc9);
                    }else if(s.equals(شيء)){
                        message=getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc0);   
                    }

                    txtv2.setText(message);
                    txtv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.listtitle1));
                    // Toast.makeText( arg0.getContext(), message,
```

Is there any option to passe a value, like in HTML elements value="1" in android xml array. If there is a way, I can compare array elements with that value instead of actual array element name.

however plz help me to correct this.

thx inadvance..

Comment: Your editor is not allowing you to save Unicode characters. Try changing the encoding of editor to "UTF-8"

Comment: eclipse shows that message I wil try thanks

Comment: You should get the editor settings in Window > Preferences

Comment: but most important thing is I want to know whether I can passe more information from the array(not only array elements)

Comment: } else if(s.equals(ذلك)){
                        message = getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc9);
                    }else if(s.equals(شيء)){
                        message=getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc0);   
                    }

Comment: else if(s.equals(ذلك)) I hadnt put "" around the arabic string this is a onoe error I found and saving aas utf-8 remove errors

Answer (score 1):

after working several ours on this problem what I understood was,
when we passe values from string array in a string file, we can not catch values properly following values (arabic letters and – values). when I debug I notice that always 0 value for postion in onitemselectedListner() methode.

```
<string-array name="country_arrays">

        <item>لا شيء</item>
        <item>5 &#8211; 9</item>
        <item>10 &#8211; 14</item>
        <item>15 &#8211; 19</item>
        <item>20 &#8211; 24</item>
        <item>25 &#8211; 35</item>
        <item>36 &#8211; 45</item>

</string-array>
```

Therefore, I had to fill list in the java file with the above content. Then I noticed that data is passed properly to lisner method. If we use characters  (A, B ... etc) we dont want to worry. all this issue was with Arabic letters.(I dont know why Layout file can not passe properly Arabic letters to java files).

Then I manage the code as follows.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("لا شيء");
        list.add("5 - 9");
        list.add("10 - 14");
        list.add("15 - 19");

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        //Log.v(LogApp,"mint value is:" + mint);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                String s = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();

                if (s.equals("لا شيء")) {
                    message = getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc0);

                } else if (s.equals("5 - 9")) {
                    message = getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc1);
                } else if (s.equals("10 - 14")) {
                    message = getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc2);
                } else if (s.equals("15 - 19")) {
                    message = getResources().getString(R.string.listdesc3);
                }               txtv2.setText(message);
                //txtv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.listtitle1));
                // Toast.makeText( arg0.getContext(), message,
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
```